# Bash script for queue between request?

Tags: linux, bash, server

I want to run a bash script when a request comes from a server.
My code is when request come from request1, reboot server with ip1.
For test, I write "a" for sample request.

I want a script when 2 request come at the same time, first request runs first and then the second request runs!

Is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=request
arr1=(request1 request2 request3)
arr2=(ip1 ip2 ip3)

user=user
password=123456
if [ $a = ${arr1[0]} ]; then
    b=${arr2[0]}
    echo $b
elif [ $a = ${arr1[1]} ]; then
    b=${arr2[1]}
    echo $b
elif [ $a = ${arr1[2]} ]; then
    b=${arr2[2]}
    echo $b
fi

id=$b
expect2=$(expect -c "
spawn ssh $user@$id
expect \"continue connecting (yes/no)?\"
send \"yes\r\"
expect \"password:\"
send \"$password\r\"
expect -exact \":~$\"
send \"sudo shutdown -r now\r\"
expect \"password:\"
send \"$password\r\"
expect -exact \":~$\"
")
echo "$expect2"
```

Comment: You can use a text file to keep current request count and you can handle the status according to current request number

Comment: could you tell me how?